# How can I blue-pencil / tween?

Tags: keyframes

I want to see what my armature looks like in the previous keyframe so I know how to make the next keyframe relative to it. How can I do this?

A simple way to draw on the screen temporarily will let me mark off where the first keyframe is, so I can reference it when editing the second one, or if there's a way of simply showing the first keyframe under my current keyframe, that would be great too.

Comment: are you looking for the Onion Skin?

Comment: Apparently, yes. That wasn't the term in college 30 years ago... Thank you.

Comment: So I hope you've found it?

Comment: Ah. No. Actually *finding* it is a whole 'nother task - even when viewing tutorials. Because, of course, my display looks nothing like theirs.

Comment: The tutorial I'm looking at shows it after 'Motion Tracking' in 'Views', but it' not there in mine.